# Laravel Mix Sourcemaps not generating for production build

Tags: webpack, sass, minify, source-maps, laravel-mix

I have the following webpack.mix.js setup for my Laravel Mix script:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
let LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new LiveReloadPlugin({
            port: '35729',
        })
    ],
});

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.disableNotifications();
}

mix
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
        processCssUrls: false,
    })
    .setPublicPath('./static')
    .sass('./resources/sass/app.scss', 'css')
    .sourceMaps(true, 'source-map')
    .version();


mix
    .options({
        postCss: [
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
        processCssUrls: false,
    })
    .setPublicPath('./static')
    .sass('./resources/sass/login.scss', 'css')
    .sourceMaps(true, 'source-map')
    .version();
```

When I run `npm run development` I get the following output (including Sourcemaps)

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 5987ms                                                                                                                                                                              12:35:24

            Asset      Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
      css/app.css   343 KiB     mix  [emitted]        mix
  css/app.css.map   400 KiB     mix  [emitted] [dev]  mix
    css/login.css   163 KiB     mix  [emitted]        mix
css/login.css.map   236 KiB     mix  [emitted] [dev]  mix
       mix.js.map  3.73 KiB     mix  [emitted] [dev]  mix
```

However, if I run `npm run production` I get the following output (without Sourcemaps)

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 9029ms                                                                                                                                                                              12:33:57

        Asset      Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
  css/app.css   278 KiB       0  [emitted]        [big]  mix
css/login.css   129 KiB       0  [emitted]               mix
   mix.js.map  4.52 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]         mix
```

I'm using Laravel Mix 5.0.1, and haven't been able to find a solution through other bug issues/SO questions -- they all seem to relate to sourcemaps not working on development and fixing it using `devtools: 'inline-source-map'` which is not relevant here.

The only thing I could think of was the minification causing an issue, as the webpack docs suggest (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool):

> If the default webpack minimizer has been overridden (such as to customise the terser-webpack-plugin options), make sure to configure its replacement with sourceMap: true to enable SourceMap support.

I couldn't find any documentation with Laravel Mix to support this though.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

you should set `false` to `generateForProduction` parameter in `mix.sourceMaps()` function

[image: mix.sourceMaps() accepts some parameters]